# jquery undelegate not working

Tags: jquery, events

I have some code which is using delegate method of jquery.

e.g.:

```
$(document).delegate('.forImg','dblclick',function(event){.
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I have multiple elements with the same class but different ids (unique). My application requires me to stop an event for some element. If I use the same syntax as the delegate for undelegate it removes the event for all the elements with that class. e.g

```
$(document).undelegate('.forImg','dblclick');
```

But I actually want to remove the event only for a particular element with a particular id. I have tried many combinations wherein I am giving the selector as that id. But no effect the elements still continue to respond to the event.

I have read that a single handler is created for the document where the selector is checked. I guess thats why even if i ask it to undelegate the handler continues to execute.

How should I do this without having to give delegate for each element?
That is why the classes are given. But I need control on each elements events.

Any help/ suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is it imperative that you are delegating? In other words, is your content dynamic? If your page is static per load, you don't need to delegate to the document to be a listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alrighty, I thought of something after all...

So, you've delegated a listener. On double-click of any of the selected elements, a function will execute, right?

But if you bind ANOTHER double-click listener over top of it, and stop propagation, it will no longer bubble up:

```
$('#SOMEID').bind('dblclick', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5e2e/7/

Note: I'm using 'bind' because the OP seems to be using older syntax for whatever reason (not everyone is using jQuery 1.7+), but if the latest jQuery is used, swap `on` in place of `bind`.

Comment: should i delegate again when I want the behaviour restrored?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to unbind in case of another button click and then the behaviour gets restored. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

WHen you delegate the handler the first time you could use not() to exclude the one ID and use a separate call to delegate to that ID so you can remove independent of the class handler

```
$(document).delegate('.forImg:not(#SOMEID)','dblclick',function(event)......

$(document).delegate('#SOMEID','dblclick',function(event)......
```

Comment: for this I will have to know beforehand which one i would remove! that is dynamically known so cant do this...

Comment: @kavita but you MUST already know the ID! Your whole premise is that you're selecting the excluded element based on ID. Dynamic or not, you must know the ID.

Comment: there is one other possibilty  ...testing  `event.target` but somehow that one element would need a separate class added, or a way to identify it with some attribute

Comment: I only know the id which i want to undelegate when it is time to undelegate. means i could have 10 divs with the same class and unique id's while delegating so i am using the above delegate call. When user has clicked once I get the id he has clicked on then i want to undelegate the event for only that div. Do you think i should remove the class for such functionality

Comment: without knowing how your app works it's hard to make any more suggestions... if you can think of some other event that would let you add another class to the element, then you can test if that class exists

Answer (score 0):

You can not use just the namespace in [.undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) like `.unbind()`. So you should use a tag name along with the class name like `div.forImg`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p5e2e/

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding the question. Given a particular class, kativa doesn't want to undelegate them all, but rather just one, based on ID. Here's a (non-functional) fiddle to serve as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/p5e2e/2/

Comment: tagname is also irrelevant...  to undelegate, selector must be the same as original

Comment: greg is right. i am setting delegate to all at once but need to remove one at a time. So there is no way out for my situation!!!

Comment: @kavita: Yeah I misread the question but greg's solution is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [.on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by .on(). In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods:

```
$(document).delegate('.forImg:not(#SOMEID)','dblclick',function(event));  // jQuery 1.4.3+ 
$(document).on('.forImg:not(#SOMEID)','dblclick',function(event));        // jQuery 1.7+`
```

And **you need to know the id**. If your content is dynamic & you are using php then you could use:

```
<div class='something' id='<?php echo "dynamic".$i;?>' >
```

while **$i** increases within a loop (MySQL while etc...).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: @GregPettit, I edited my question to propose a solution for the asker. Initially I posted only the "needed" information because I just started using SO and I dont know how to post links in comments :)